# How do I stop IT Recruiters from sending SPAM?

Tags: email, recruiting

I have received thousands of emails from IT recruiters asking me to hire their clients.

I have asked them repeatedly to Cease and Desist and yet they keep up the spamming.  One IT firm sent me over 1300 emails in one day.

What else can I do to make the company stop?

**Editing in detail to the OP added to their question in an answer**

Some of the spamming IT recruiters change their ISP addresses and they start all over again. Actually, it is an old Juno account. I have relatives that use Juno as their ISP. Why I don't know.

Comment: Are you sure these are from legitimate IT firms?  It sounds like you're being spammed by people pretending to be IT recruiters and firms.

Comment: I don't see how this is a workplace question.

Comment: @Andy best fit might be SuperUser, but even there this might be off-topic.

Comment: @Andy - As it stands, possibly not, but answers (or an edited question) might be useful for workplaces with a similar problem - or for workplaces planning to send unsolicited mail.

Comment: @ItWasLikeThatWhenIGotHere I think that's a pretty large stretch to make.  This question and its answers should be likely on serverfault or superuser.

Comment: @Andy - I was thinking of a legal solution ("how can I stop" rather than "how can I block or avoid seeing") - none of the technical suggestions will prevent spam having been sent. If the question is going elsewhere, I'm inclined towards Law, but I'll try an edit to strip out the bit that's causing people to think "not Workplace",

Answer (score 15):

> What else can I do to make the company stop?

**Mark those mails as SPAM**, usually Gmail will then start to recognize such emails and start filtering them.

If I am not mistaken, you can even indicate that certain account or sender is SPAMming you, and mark them as such to filter those mails.

More info on Gmail spam handling [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1366858?co=GENIE.Platform%3DiOS&hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

Find out if they're a legitimate business.

- If so, call them and send a letter to the address stated on their website / their business entries in things like official corporate registries.

If this won't help or instead of getting in touch on your own, have a lawyer send an appropriate letter and contact authorities if spamming is illegal in their jurisdiction if they continue their activities.

- If they're not legitimate ignore their spam, don't reply (!) and set up your email client / ISP to filter them out

Comment: Even if unsolicited email isn't illegal, 1300 messages in one day might qualify as harassment.

Comment: good point. There are many countries with laws against unsolicited marketing (i.e. CAN-SPAM Act of 2003 USA, Privacy and Electronic Communications Directive 2002 EU and others) in which they are either declared illegal or in certain cases open up legal ways to stop them.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a legitimate IT firm, opt out.  Legitimate IT firms won't push back with more spam; even if they don't have good reputations, they don't sink to the level of spamming after opting out.

If it is a scammer posing as an IT firm, use Google's "this is spam" button.  Don't use it for legitimate IT firms, because they are maintaining mailing lists going to other clients besides you, and your actions might cause a whole list block.

If you aren't using Google and it is not a legitimate company, set up a mail action to mark the message as read and then delete it, using the source email address as the trigger.  While this doesn't fix the issue, it does lessen the impact.

True fixes to the issue require a lot of work if the company doesn't maintain or honor a removal process.  The kind of work that involves lawyers and spending your money.  If you want to go that route, look to a lawyer, telling the lawyer you want to cause them the most legal expense while minimizing your legal expense.

Comment: "your actions might cause a whole list block." - for sending 1300 messages in a day, I would have very little sympathy with the company for getting themsleves on a block-list. Spam is spam, regardless of how legitimate their intent is.

Comment: @Bilkokuya You lack of sympathy is not relevant when you filter my job opportunities.  If you block what others legitimately want, the tables are turned in such a way that you become the problem you were trying to solve.  Let's all be good citizens, permitting those who want the service, and opting out when we don't want the service.

Comment: @EdwinBuck: Your perceived right to hear about job opportunities does not include forcing others to carry the costs.

Comment: @BenVoigt I'm not suggesting that they carry the costs.  I'm suggesting that they opt-out instead of marking it all as garbage.

Answer (score -1):

In terms of how you, as a private individual, can "make them stop", there's little you can do, and it sounds like you've already tried.

On the question of who (possibly) could, it will depend on jurisdiction. In the EU, you would be covered by GDPR, and could refer a complaint to your national or regional regulator - for example the UK Information Commissioner's Office (https://ico.org.uk/make-a-complaint/).

Since you mention Juno, I would guess you're in the US. It's not quite as simple, but this article https://iapp.org/news/a/america-doesnt-have-a-national-data-protection-authority-think-again/ might give you some useful ideas.

It's not a perfect system, and if the organisation sending the spam is in another jurisdiction things could be tricky, but making a complaint is still worth doing - if your regulator isn't able to do anything, your complaint will draw that to their attention and may lead to protection for others in a similar position.

There might also be a possibility of Civil Legal Action if you can show damages, though I'm not a lawyer so you would need to talk to one to see if this is a possibility.

Otherwise, the suggestions of how you can block or avoid particular senders would be worth following - but bear in mind that if you're intending to take the Regulator or Civil Action route, the more information you have, the better the evidence against them.